# PHP 5.4 and PEAR mail

Tags: php, pear

I have some important scripts on my website at "1and1 Internet" that have been using PEAR mail under PHP 5.2. Since it's not my server, I have no control over what's installed.

They recently sent an email informing me that they now have PHP 5.4 available and will be removing earlier versions in a few months. So I switched my account config to try the scripts on 5.4 and found that they fail! The failure is on the `require_once` lines for `Mail.php` and `Mail/mime.php`, presumably because they don't exist or can't be found.

Looking at output from `phpinfo()`, it looks to me like the same `--with-pear` config switch is there in both versions, but on 5.4 I also see something to do with PEAR in a section about `Phar`, and I have no idea what Phar is!

Anyway, is there something more specific that I can try before attempting to contact support at 1and1? Fortunately I am able to return things to 5.2 until I get it all working!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check if `pear` is installed.

I assume you have shell access, so that would be simply:

```
$ pear
```

That would give you a list of commands if `pear` is installed.

Then you need to install the `Mail` package (probably as root...):

```
$ pear install Mail
```

And other packages you might need like `Mail_Mime`, etc.

Comment: He has no control over what is installed

Comment: @Phil I saw that, but I assumed that `pear` would probably be installed and that perhaps the OP would be able install pear packages. If not, the question is simply unanswerable, but this is what I would try...

Comment: It's definitely something not installed or configured correctly on the server, but I'm having trouble getting through to someone who knows what is what. Rather than keep depending on things that are not in my control, I'll probably just switch to something I can maintain myself, such as Swiftmail.

Comment: @gordonwd That is always a good idea, although following that thought you would at least need some kind of VPS where you can manage the (virtual...) server itself as well...